# Trying to understand the meaning of "<body class="is-preload">" in code

Tags: html, class

I'm still quite a beginner with HTML but I wanted to know what this means exactly:

```html
<body class="is-preload">
```

I saw it in a template of a website for the index.html page. I'm asking as I am trying to learn and combing through website templates to get an understanding of each line of code's role, I thought that the body itself was already a class. Apologies if this is an incredibly softball question to ask, but still trying to learn the semantics.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Arielle, welcome to SO. Yes, quite softball, but you posed a nice question that asks an exact issue that you have been struggling with. As long as your question fits most of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you are fine!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that the body itself was already a class.

`body` is an element **type**.

Classes are freeform identifiers assigned to elements which can be used by CSS, JavaScript and anything else that processes HTML to group elements more narrowly than by type.

See:

- [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) on MDN
- CSS [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) on MDN
- DOM [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) on MDN